# Evaluate String Formula with External Link

Tags: excel, vba, string, external

I am trying to evaluate a string as a formula.  The formula contains a reference to another workbook within the string.

```
MyString="MATCH(""Keyword"",'FileFolder\[MyWorkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A100,0)"
```

If this string is input into the workbook as a formula (with the = in front), it works properly.  The string/path is generated other information in the workbook using standard Excel formulas.  I can get the formulas to work by replacing/adding the = sign to the formula text.  However, I'd like to be able to call a function that does this directly.  I have used VBA's evaluate property to do this within a separate function, but I am receiving an error.

When I call the function to evaluate the string, I can actually see the correct value within the formula bar.  However, the actual value returns a reference error once accept the formula.  For a few instances using an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) resolves this problem, but generally speaking this doesn't help.  Any ideas on how to create a formula that will evaluate the match formula within the string.

```
Function WSEval(FormulaString)
'allows string given in workbook to be evaluated
WSEval = Evaluate(FormulaString)
End Function


Function GetExternalDataFromString()

'WorkbookPath As String, RangeString As String)
'Testing Using Fixed Arguments for Now
WorkbookPath = "'\\FileFolder\[FileName.xlsx]"
RangeString = "Sheet1'!A1:A100"

FullString = WorkbookPath & RangeString

AllString = "=MATCH(""Total Costs"",'\\FileFolder\[FileName.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A100,0)"

'Note: Function works in formula bar but still returns reference error.

GetExternalDataFromString = Application.Evaluate(AllString)

End Function
```

Comment: What are these extra variables here? `WorkbookPath` and `RangeString`? In `WorkbookPath` you use `FileName.xlsx`, but in `AllString` you're using `MyWorkbook.xlsx` - have you double checked these file names?

Comment: I've double checked the filenames.  I have used a generic name, rather than the full workbook name and path.  For example, FileName.xlsx is the filename, and the file folder path includes the full path.  For some reason, I can get the formula to evaluate correctly (when reviewing the formula bar), but when I click enter I get a reference area.  This seems like it should be some sort of input/output issue, but I can't seem to find a way to fix it.